# Telegram bot only for send messages

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

I want a Telegram bot notify me when a user do some action in my website. I have been testing Telegram bots to send messages and using getUpdates via polling to receive, and everything works perfectly. I have read than the polling method consume more CPU than webhooks (because it is constantly checking for new messages), but this is more complicated to implement, so I discard webhooks.

Actually, I don't need to use the polling or webhooks, because what I want is to send messages, but I have to implement the getUpdates method compulsory. Is there any way to use only the send message function and avoid the receive messages? Like a only-read bot or a telegram channel.

Thanks!

**EDIT**. Here is my code in Java:

```
public class TelegramBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        // Stuff when the bot receive a message
        // I don't need this method, but it is compulsory to implement it
    }

    public synchronized void sendMsg(String msg) {
        // Stuff to send a message 
        // Here goes the code I only need
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        // Compulsory to implement
        return "my_bot_user_name";
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        // Compulsory to implement
        return "my_token";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved all using **Jersey WS** (`jersey-client` and `jersey-common` packages)

This is how my code looks now, just calling it when I need it and not polling at all:

```
private static int sendMessage(String message) {
    HttpResponse<String> response = null;
    
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
            .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
            .build();

    UriBuilder builder = UriBuilder
            .fromUri("https://api.telegram.org")
            .path("/{token}/sendMessage")
            .queryParam("chat_id", CHAT_ID)
            .queryParam("text", message)
            .queryParam("parse_mode", "html");

    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .GET()
            .uri(builder.build("bot" + TELEGRAM_TOKEN))
            .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
            .build();
    try {
        response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    }
    catch(IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
        LOGGER.warn("Error sending message to Telegram Bot");
    }

    return (response != null) ? response.statusCode() : -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to configure and start the chatbot without actually performing the polling

```
 updater = Updater('token', use_context=True)

 dp = updater.dispatcher
 updater.idle()

 updater.bot.send_message(chat_id='YYYY', text='hoi')
```

In this case there is no polling but a message is sent to the chat.

Notice:

- you need to know the chat id
- updater.idle() is needed only if you need keep running the chatbot (otherwise you can just send the message(s) and shutdown the application)

Comment: Thank for your reply. In java, when I develop a bot, i have to create a method called getUpdates() compulsory using polling. How to create just a calling like you said?

Comment: I provided an example in Python, but the idea is the same in each language/framework for Telegram. If you share some code maybe I can point out some hints

Comment: Looks like you need to implement the method because it takes care of the authentication, which you need to get and send messages. I would try to implement it but ignore the incoming messages.

Comment: The problem is that method is always checking for new messages, so it is consuming CPU and I don't need that :(

Comment: Indeed you dont. The Webhook is the option to avoid this, but I understand it brings extra complexity